# Nonstable estimates for GARCH(1,1) for different initials using MLE in R

Tags: r, estimation, optimization, garch

I want to estimate a GARCH(1,1) proces manually using maximum likelihood function which is also related to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118578/garch1-1-estimation-using-maximum-likelihood-estimation-manually).

I wrote the below code:

```
library(fGarch)

#generate returns 
set.seed(1)
garch11<-garchSpec(model = list())
y<-garchSim(garch11, n = 1000)

n<-length(y)
sigma2<- vector(length = n)


#estimating the parameters manually by mle
LL <- function(theta) 
{

    sigma2[1]<-theta[1]/(1-theta[2]-theta[3])
   #sigma2[1]<-var(y)

  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    sigma2[i+1]<-theta[1]+theta[2]*y[i]^2+theta[3]*sigma2[i]
  }

  R =dnorm(y[1:n], 0, sqrt(sigma2[1:n]), log = TRUE)
  L=-sum(R)
  return(L)
}


fit1<-optim(theta<-c(0.1,0.,0.1),LL)
fit2<-optim(theta<-c(0.0001,0.5,0.1),LL)
```

I use two set of initial values. Then I get two different set of estimates(probably local minimums).

```
> fit1
$par
[1] 0.000007919175 0.139449431273 0.190760467531

$value
[1] -4264.499

$counts
function gradient 
     250       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

> fit2
$par
[1] 0.000001281119 0.100213870720 0.790732098375

$value
[1] -4275.474

$counts
function gradient 
     314       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

fit2 results are very close to the true parameter values. However fit1 is far to the true.

This is just an experiment for me. If I convince I will use the above code to estimate some models' parameters. However, getting different results for different initial values make me not trust to the code.

How can I improve the code to get more stable estimates?

Comment: thats rather stats related. If you choose `(0.1,0.,0.1)` as initial parameters for GARCH you cant expect reasonable parameter estimates,...

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ BigDataScientist . The initial that you recomended reasonable for GARCH(1,1). But I am seeking a general method to determine initials. I also want to make estimations for for different GARCH models(ex:GARCH(2,1) or EGARCH). Can you advice me an article or source for a method? By the you are right the topic is reated to stat. I did should open thsi topic in stat.stack. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also wanted to do a manual MLE once and found the `mle()`function very unstable, due to the sensitivity to the starting value choice. Trying the `solnp()`function from the `Rsolnp`package worked for me - here's the code:

```
#data <- "your data set"
library(Rsolnp)
solfun<-function(vec) 
{
    alpha<-vec[1];
    beta<-vec[2];
    omega<-vec[3];
    mu<-vec[4]; #only if you want to include a mean in the GARCH model, else set mu=0
    sig0<-vec[5]; #starting value estimation can be replaced by sd(data)
    LL_ret<-1:(length(data));
    sigs<-1:(length(data)+1);
    sigs[1]<-sig0^2 ;
    for(i in 2:(length(data)+1)) (sigs[i] <- (omega+alpha*(data[i-1]-mu)^2+beta*sigs[i-1])) ;
    for(i in 1:(length(data))) (LL_ret[i] <- (-0.5*log(2*pi*sigs[i])-((data[i]-mu)^2)/(2*sigs[i]))) ;
    return(sum(-LL_ret)) ;
} #negative log likelihood that we want to minimize

#optimization:
sol<-solnp(pars=c(alpha=0.1, beta=0.9, omega=0, mu=mean(data),sig0=sd(data)),
fun=solfun,LB=c(0,0.7,0,-1,0),UB=c(0.3,1,1,1,1)) #mu and sig0 only if you use them in solfun

#plugging the estimated parameters into function for sigma^2 estimates:
LL2<-function(alpha, beta, omega, mu, sig0) 
{
    LL_ret<-1:(length(data));
    sigs<-1:(length(data)+1);
    sigs[1]<-sig0^2 ;
    for(i in 2:(length(data)+1)) (sigs[i] <- (omega+alpha*(data[i-1]-mu)^2+beta*sigs[i-1])) ;
    for(i in 1:(length(data))) (LL_ret[i] <- (-0.5*log(2*pi*sigs[i])-((data[i]-mu)^2)/(2*sigs[i]))) ;
    return(list(LL_ret,sigs)) ;
}

L2<-LL2(alpha=sol$pars[[1]],beta=sol$pars[[2]],
    omega=sol$pars[[3]],mu=sol$pars[[4]],sig0=sol$pars[[5]])

#Summarizing results of log likelihood, parameters and sigma estimates:
GG1<-list(sigma=sqrt(L2[[2]]),llh=L2[[1]],llhs=sum(L2[[1]]),coef=sol$pars)
```

If you don't want to estimate the mean and starting value, you just have to remove those parts. Also, you'll obviously have to adjust the parameter bounds in the optimization, to fit your data (in my case, it was financial return data). It doesn't have to be as exact, as for the `mle()` function, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eldioo. As you told your code gives more stable estimates. However, I also feel I have to study on determinig initial values as    BigDataScientist mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that certainly is a prerequisite. Small hint regarding this: You can take a look at the autocorrelation function of your squared data, to get a feeling for the persistence of shocks. The longer the function values remain significant, the closer `alpha+beta` is to 1. Typically, financial returns have an `alpha` value around 0.1 and a `beta` value of about 0.9, with a very high persistence, i.e. there sum is close to 1.

Comment: Regarding the problem of choosing starting values, the "Rsolnp" package also offers the nice function "gosolnp" which draws a large number of random starting values and starts the solver from the one with the best guess. Since you only have three parameters, this approach actually works quite well.